# How to include the schema with the xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, xsd

When I create a XML file using the `XmlSerializer` and attempt to open it in excel I get the following message:

```
The specified XML source does not refer to a schema. 
Excel will create a schema based on the XML source data.
```

Is there any way to include the schema in the xml file so Excel (or any other program) does not need to calculate it?

Here is a example program showing how I am creating my xml file.

```
namespace Sandbox_Console
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            List<MyClass> test = new List<MyClass>();

            test.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Test", Foo = "Shazam"});
            test.Add(new MyClass() { Name = "Test2", Foo = "Shazam2" });

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<MyClass>));
            using (var file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\srchamberlain\Desktop\test.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                ser.Serialize(file, test);
            }
        }

    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string Foo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The generated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfMyClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MyClass Name="Test">
    <Foo>Shazam</Foo>
  </MyClass>
  <MyClass Name="Test2">
    <Foo>Shazam2</Foo>
  </MyClass>
</ArrayOfMyClass>
```

In my real file that I am generating the file size is over 300 MB large and it is taking a long time for the data to be parsed out, my hope is that by providing the schema it can decrease the time it takes to process the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the XSD file you can load it into Excel, then set Excel to use this schema into your file. Just follow this guide http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/using-xml-in-excel.php 
In this way you can save the Excel file as XML data, and this is just validated with your schema.

Answer (score 0):

XML is, by it's very nature, a rather verbose syntax.  Consider writing to CSV directly, or use XLSB via OLE.  XLSB retains native Excel formatting, but is a binary compact format which is quick to load.